# CakePHP Url query string of GET action

Tags: cakephp

May be the title not showing what I have to do,sorry for my bad English

I have form in cakephp like that :

```
<form action='/search' method="get">
 <input type=text name="keyword"/>
 <input type=text name="category"/>
 <input type=submit value="Search" />
</form>
```

When I click submit : url will be : `/search?keyword=XXXX&category=YYYY`

Now I want change it to cakephp format like : `/search/keyword:XXXX/category:YYYY`

Is it possible? 
//Im using 1.3 version . Can not be update to 3.0 because it is the big project

Comment: You can use jquery to send form data

Comment: I dont want to use ajax, just a simple get action request